# The limit of questions concerning Mathematical Software

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I looked through the questions about programming and software, and I couldn't seem to find anything that was asking what I wanted to ask. If I've missed something I apologize.

I answered two questions today relating specifically to sage. They can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185572/create-graph-in-sage/185592#185592) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185534/converting-gap-groups-into-sage-permutation-groups/185539#185539). I'm not sure that I feel either of these questions is entirely suited to math.se. I am sure both are better suited to [asksage](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/). But when reading both questions I saw an easy solution rather quickly and figured so why not post it here, since it's more convenient. There's a certain grey area that some questions fall into where they're appropriate to be asked on multiple sites, such as complexity theory questions being asked on math.se as opposed to cstheory.se or research level questions occasionally being posted on math.se as opposed to MO. Ultimately I'm unsure if questions such as the ones I answered fall into that gray area or are more off topic. By answering those questions, I'm in some sense encouraging questions pertaining to sage to be posted on math.se. So I'm wondering where the line, fuzzy or not, is drawn with regards to questions about math suites.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the first few lines of the [Faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) say that **questions about software that mathematicians use are welcomed in this site**, so since this is actually explicit in there, I don't see any reason why such questions could be off-topic.

---

**About ask.sagemath.org**

From personal experience, I've noticed that some (or actually most) of the questions asked in the ask.sagemath.org website get a really low number of views compared to the exposure they get in math.stackexchange.

For example, I once asked a question about a computation with modular forms first in ask.sagemath.org and didn't get an answer. But then I reposted my question here and I got an answer from the author of the book I was using.

So I believe that at least for now, the idea that someone might have better luck with their SAGE related question getting a satisfactory answer in ask.sagemath.org might not be true in some cases (in particular maybe with questions related to computations with somewhat more advanced objects).